# Multiple file rename

Tags: powershell

I'm a powershell newbie. I have gotten the names of files in a folder using the `Get-ChildItem`cmdlet.

The names follow this scheme:

```
video_536_640Seg1-Frag3
video_536_640Seg1-Frag4
video_536_640Seg1-Frag7
```

The desired output is to have the files follow this scheme:

```
Frag3-video_536_640Seg1
Frag4-video_536_640Seg1
```

This can be achieved by splitting each file name by the hyphen, then switching the order of each split piece.

I've tried splitting using `-split`,

```
$items = $files -split "-"
```

but each component is sent to a different array index and I've been unable to sort the indexes.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an optimally elegant solution, but will give you insight on approaching future problems you face with Powershell (while also proving a valid answer). You will need to update the extension to actually match your video files.

```
# change below to match the file extension of the video files
$extension = ".mp4"
$files = gci *$extension

ForEach ($file in $files) {
    # get everything before "-"
    $a = ($file.BaseName).split('-')[0]

    # get everything after "-"
    $b = ($file.BaseName).split('-')[1]

    # setup the desired name format
    $fixed = $b + "-" + $a + $extension

    # rename the files
    Rename-Item $file $fixed
}
```